# pandas dataframe multiply / formula the bottom row to top row

Tags: python, pandas, loops

Need to add math formula to calculate result based on row below, all the way to top of dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

n = 2

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 4, 8, 7, 1, 8, 2, 4],'B': [10, 2, 1, 8, 2, 4, 8, 7]})

df.loc[7, 'C'] = df.loc[7, 'A']

print(df)
```

print the above then read below:

I want to make the cell above 4.0 (ie cell C6) in column C the following:

```
((4.0 (cell c7) * 2) + cellA6 (ie 2.0)/n) = 5
```

then cell C5 being the following

```
((5.0 (cell c6) * 2) + cellA5 (ie 8.0)/n) = 9
```

etc

So I need to make a calculation starting on the second last cell in column C based on the bottom/last .loc cell in column C. After the second cell is calculated the above cells are continually calculated on its below cell rolling all the way to the top of the dataframe

Comment: This should be ((4.0 (cell c7) * 2) + cellA6 (ie 2.0)/n) = 9 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try iterating backwords through the `DataFrame` with a `for loop` and updating the value of `"C"` with `loc`:

```
for idx in df.index[::-1][:-1]:
    df.loc[idx - 1, 'C'] = (df.loc[idx, 'C'] * 2 + df.loc[idx - 1, 'A']) / n

print(df)

   A   B     C
0  2  10  20.0
1  4   2  19.0
2  8   1  17.0
3  7   8  13.0
4  1   2   9.5
5  8   4   9.0
6  2   8   5.0
7  4   7   4.0
```

Comment: Your a modern day hero. Its exactly what I needed. Thank you. This is my first question. Can I rate you or is there an option to give you a score or something?

Comment: Happy to help buddy. Accepting the answer is appreciated :) thanks